iOS touch/touchstart cause HTML canvas lag
Seems like iOS cause lag when tapping on html canvas using requestAnimation frame.
I've made a codepen with a simple js canvas game - when you tap the canvas it causes minor lag spikes/jitter/freeze. The issue seems to only be on iPhone iOS - works fine on pc and android
https://codepen.io/Sebastian-Jakobsen/pen/zYQBGjX?editors=1010
Im wondering if anybody know a fix for this?
Here is a small video of the issue: https://imgur.com/a/1A80GTZ


const gameCanvas = document.getElementById('gameCanvas');
let context = gameCanvas.getContext('2d');
let requestId = null;
let lastTime = 0;
let pickupTimer = 0;
let obstacleTimer = 0;

const chopper = {
  x: 50,
  y: 150,
  width: 50,
  height: 20,
  dy: 0,
};

let pickups = new Set();
let obstacles = new Set();
const pickupWidth = 10;
const pickupHeight = 10;
const obstacleWidth = 30;
const obstacleHeight = 30;
let score = 0;
let gameRunning = true;
let gameSpeed = -0.5;
let isFlapping = false;

function spawnPickup(delta) {
  pickupTimer += delta;
  if (pickupTimer >= 0.5) { // 0.5 seconds interval
    const x = context.canvas.width;
    const y = Math.random() * (context.canvas.height - pickupHeight);
    pickups.add({ x, y, width: pickupWidth, height: pickupHeight, value: 10, dx: gameSpeed });
    pickupTimer = 0;
  }
}

function spawnObstacle(delta) {
  obstacleTimer += delta;
  if(obstacleTimer >= 0.6) { // 0.6 seconds interval
    const x = context.canvas.width;
    const y = Math.random() * (context.canvas.height - obstacleHeight);
    obstacles.add({ x, y, width: obstacleWidth, height: obstacleHeight, dx: gameSpeed});
    obstacleTimer = 0;
  }
}

function drawPickup(pickup) {
  context.fillStyle = 'gold';
  context.fillRect(pickup.x, pickup.y, pickup.width, pickup.height);
}

function drawObstacle(obstacle) {
  context.fillStyle = 'red';
  context.fillRect(obstacle.x, obstacle.y, obstacle.width, obstacle.height);
}

function drawChopper(deltaTime) {
  if (isFlapping) {
    chopper.dy = -0.3;
    isFlapping = false;
  }
  chopper.dy += 0.0009 * deltaTime; // Adjust gravity and flapping force by delta time
  chopper.y += chopper.dy * deltaTime;

  if (chopper.y + chopper.height > context.canvas.height || chopper.y < 0) {
    endGame();
  }

  context.fillStyle = 'green';
  context.fillRect(chopper.x, chopper.y, chopper.width, chopper.height);
}

function checkCollision(rect1, rect2) {
  return rect1.x < rect2.x + rect2.width &&
    rect1.x + rect1.width > rect2.x &&
    rect1.y < rect2.y + rect2.height &&
    rect1.y + rect1.height > rect2.y;
}

function handlePickupOverlap(deltaTime) {
  pickups.forEach(pickup => {
    pickup.x += pickup.dx * deltaTime; // Adjust by delta time
    drawPickup(pickup);
    if (checkCollision(chopper, pickup)) {
      score += pickup.value;
      pickups.delete(pickup);
    } else if (pickup.x + pickup.width < 0) {
      pickups.delete(pickup);
    }
  });
}

function handleObstacleOverlap(deltaTime) {
  obstacles.forEach(obstacle => {
    obstacle.x += obstacle.dx * deltaTime; // Adjust by delta time
    drawObstacle(obstacle);
    // if (checkCollision(chopper, obstacle)) {
    //   endGame();
    // } else if (obstacle.x + obstacle.width < 0) {
    //   obstacles.delete(obstacle);
    // }
  });
}

function updateGame(timestamp = 0) {
  const deltaTime = timestamp - lastTime; // Convert to seconds
  lastTime = timestamp;

  if (gameRunning) {
    context.clearRect(0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height);

    drawChopper(deltaTime);
    spawnPickup(deltaTime)
    spawnObstacle(deltaTime)

    handlePickupOverlap(deltaTime);

    handleObstacleOverlap(deltaTime);

    requestId = requestAnimationFrame(updateGame);
  }
}

function endGame() {
  // gameRunning = false;

  // just reset for testing
  chopper.y = 140
  chopper.dy = 0;
}

function setupCanvas() {
  context.canvas.width = 300;
  context.canvas.height = 600;
  requestId = requestAnimationFrame(updateGame);

  window.addEventListener('touchstart', (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    isFlapping = true;
  });
}

setupCanvas();
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Game</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="game-container">
  <canvas id="gameCanvas"></canvas>
</div>
<script type="module" src="/src/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>



I've tried to preventDefault / event.stopPropagation(); to see if maybe the device was trying to do something on touchstart, but it didn't help

I can't reproduce this on any of my iOS devices, and the video you linked to is smooth as butter (i..e I don't see any stuttering).

BTW, you should prefer for(const x of arr) {} instead of arr.forEach() because it won't create a closure which means it's more efficient, and also lets you use the continue;, break, and even goto to control iteration within the loop body - you can't do that with Array.prototype.forEach.

Also, you're missing a huge potential performance optimization: currently you're calling clearRect on every frame and having to repaint the entire scene every frame, instead it's much more efficient to simply scroll the entire canvas horizontally and only paint the newly visible region. For overlapping elements that can't scroll together, you can still render them all to an offscreen buffer and then blit the buffer with a scroll offset.

@Dai thanks for reply! What iOS version did you test? testet it myself on iPhone 13 iOS 17.15.1 and it would stutter on every tab (has also been happening on 3 other iOS devices i've testet)

After trying it again and looking more closely, I see there's a 1-2 frame pause in the <canvas> rendering when I tap the screen - so I see the problem now. Another person recently reported the same issue - so I wonder if it's a bug/behaviour recently introduced in Safari 17? If so, you should contact Apple about this.
